# how to get the all the likes from a post in restFB

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

i have been trying to get few information details that somehow always return as null. the one that is most needed for me is likes count (or even better, just all the likes. i want to know who liked the post).

my code is

```
FacebookClient fc = ~my facebook client in version 2.3~;
Post post = fc.fetchObject(anID, Post.class ;
System.out.println("Likes Count -  "+ post.getLikes().getData().size());
```

im trying like so cause this way i get the number 25. so i got it , its limited to 25. how do i get all of the likes??

by the way , if ill just try `post.getLikesCount()` ill get nothing.

if anyone knows how to handle this situation he might also know how to get `Attribution` , `Shares` and `FeedTargeting`.

thanks for you attention!

Answer (score 0):

To get all Likes of a Post you can request the `<postid>/likes` endpoint. You can iterate over the pages and the likes.

Perhaps there's a way to use the field expansion, but I'm not sure atm.